# Use mouse to scroll through tabs in JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, mousewheel, jtabbedpane

I have a `JTabbedPane` in a scroll tab layout, so that all the tabs sit nicely on one row. Is there a way to allow the user to scroll through them with the mouse wheel, or is the only way to navigate the `JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT` with the keyboard's and GUI's arrows and by clicking the tabs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did find an answer to this, after digging around Eclipse's autocomplete: use a `MouseWheelListener` for the `JTabbedPane`:

```
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
tabbedPane.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);
tabbedPane.addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {
    @Override
    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
        JTabbedPane pane = (JTabbedPane) e.getSource();
        int units = e.getWheelRotation();
        int oldIndex = pane.getSelectedIndex();
        int newIndex = oldIndex + units;
        if (newIndex < 0)
            pane.setSelectedIndex(0);
        else if (newIndex >= pane.getTabCount())
            pane.setSelectedIndex(pane.getTabCount() - 1);
        else
            pane.setSelectedIndex(newIndex);
    }
});
```

This both allows for mouse scrolling over the tabs, and respects the index bounds of the `JTabbedPane`.

If anyone has a better answer, I'd be happy to accept!

Comment: Where did you find this? Link?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I used eclipse's autocomplete to search through the event listeners, came up with the code. (tabbedPane is actually the name I use in my program, not a generic name from some tutorial)

Comment: I can certainly look around for a tutorial with more information, if that would be necessary/preferable?