# JTabbedPane - How to scroll (not select) tabs with mouse wheel (SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT)

Tags: java, swing, mouse, jtabbedpane, nimbus

When space is limited, the tabs get shown in a scroll pane, and two small arrow buttons appear. I would like to use the mouse wheel to operate these buttons.

There is a nice solution in [Use mouse to scroll through tabs in JTabbedPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38463047/use-mouse-to-scroll-through-tabs-in-jtabbedpane), but it actually selects the tabs. I only want to scroll them, without changing the selection.

How do I get these bottons or related actions?

(I am using the Nimbus LaF, if that is important.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just found it!
The drag-and-drop code in DnDTabbedPane at https://java-swing-tips.blogspot.co.at/2008/04/drag-and-drop-tabs-in-jtabbedpane.html has this very nice method:

```
private void clickArrowButton(String actionKey) {
    ActionMap map = getActionMap();
    if (map != null) {
        Action action = map.get(actionKey);
        if (action != null && action.isEnabled()) {
            action.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(
                    this, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, null, 0, 0));
        }
    }
}
```

and so I just need to say:

```
    addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
            if (e.getWheelRotation() > 0) {
                clickArrowButton("scrollTabsBackwardAction");
            } else {
                clickArrowButton("scrollTabsForwardAction");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: It's better to user `e.getPreciseWheelRotation()` that allows to scroll by trackpad (on Windows)